# Wrong fragment displayed when going to recents and back

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity A which launches a fragment F, which then gets replaced with another fragment F2.

A -> F -> F2

If I'm at F2, press the recents button, and go back into the app, I expect it to still show F2, but it instead shows F.

I'm replacing fragments using this code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(container.getId(), StoryFragment.newInstance(story)).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

I've tested this with different fragments, and it turns out that the problem is going from fragment to fragment. It doesn't matter which fragments they are, if there's a fragment that replaces itself with another fragment, then I will have this problem. For example, 
A -> F2 -> F3 will show F2 when it should show F3.

I've tried adding things to onSaveInstance and onPause, but haven't been successful in doing so. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code regarding fragment transaction.

Comment: share your code to better understand

Comment: I added the code for the fragment transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I accidentally added 
`android:noHistory="true"`
in the android manifest, for the activity I was using to launch the fragments. Removing it fixed my problem.